# Getting video details in flutter/dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a video inside my device but I want to extract the following details of the video(In flutter/dart)-
1.When the video was taken.
2.Duration of the video
3.Type of the Video
4.When the video was taken
Currently i am using Ff-mpeg plugin but it is taking too long time before it returns metadata information.

Comment: Hi Joshi. Kindly share the format of the video and a part of source code if it's possible.

Comment: Video format MP4.This code for getting file size duration metadata.
 String filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.VIDEO);
      if (filePath == '') return;
      print('Filepath>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' + filePath);
      File file =  File(filePath);
      setState(() => this.filePath = file);
      VideoPlayerController controller =
          new VideoPlayerController.file(file); //Your file here
      print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>${controller.value}');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to use FFMPEG as follows

```
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

class VideoDetail {
  final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
  VideoDetail() {
    _flutterFFmpeg
        .getMediaInformation("<file path or uri>")
        .then((info) => print(info));
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add dependency

`flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.1.1`

For more information please visit 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_ffmpeg

Comment: It worked.Thanks Santosh.

Comment: But it is taking a long time to get metadata.

Comment: This is the best solution, as it gives Map of information! easily you can get any desired value out of map.